# Disabled editmaskcontrol (powerbuilder)

Tags: powerbuilder

I am new in the world of powerbuilder

I wonder how to disabled editmask control based on the value/data inputted on the previous row?

```
long ll_row 
long ll_rowback
long ll_rownext
string ls_display_name
ll_row = currentrow
 ll_rowback = ll_row - 1
 ll_rownext = ll_row + 1
 if ll_row = 0 then
ll_row = 1
end if

//uf_log( gs_log, ls_name + ' ll_row='+string(ll_row))

 if ll_row > rowcount() then
ll_row = 1 
end if
datawindow ldw
ldw = this

if getitemstring( ll_row, 'param_type_param_type_flag' ) = 'N' then
//min and max value
dec ldc_min, ldc_max
ldc_min = getitemnumber( ll_row, 'param_value_param_value_min')
ldc_max = getitemnumber( ll_row, 'param_value_param_value_max')
 ls_display_name = describe( "evaluate('lookupdisplay    (element_attribute_param_value_key)', "+string(ll_rowback)+")" )
```

//jonel

```
if ls_display_name = 'No' or ls_display_name ='Not Known then
>>>what will be the systax here.
```

else
    uf_modify( ldw, "element_attribute_attrib_num_value.EditMask.SpinRange='" + string   (ldc_min) + "~~~~" + string(ldc_min) + "'")

end if

I try to have coded on the protect expression but nothing happen..

any idea would be appreciated.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track with coding an expression. I don't have my help/reference handy but setting "protect" or "taborder=0" or whichever attribute is applicable for disabling the editmask. I am assuming you mean an "editmask" edit style in a datawindow and not a separate control outside of the datawindow.

The trick is, that in your expression refer to the **prior row** using [-1] to refer to the next row you can use something like [+1]. Some people use this for highlighting duplicate value/rows, etc..  here is some code for hint...

```
element_attrib_num_value.protect=(if(getrow() <=1, 0, columnname_in_prior_row[-1])) 
or 
element_attrib_num_value.taborder=(if(getrow() <=1, 10, columnname_to_refer_to[-1]))
```

Don't quote my exact syntax. This method of referring to rows is only usable in expressions as far as I know, also you need to make sure to check that you aren't on the first (or none) row so the expression doesn't break. :)